# Session database table cleanup

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

Does this table need to be purged or is it taken care of automatically by Django?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Django does NOT provide automatic purging. There is however a handy command available to help you do it manually: [Django docs: Clearing the session store](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#clearing-the-session-store)

```
python manage.py clearsessions
```

Comment: If you use Django 1.5 or lower, you can use python manage.py cleanup

Comment: I was in my psql and found out that `TRUNCATE django_session;` also works.

Comment: I would check beforehand the sessions before deleting: in mysql `select*from django_session;` or to see how many there are `select count (*)from django_session;`

Comment: @Alper be careful with truncation of the table, this will effectively clear the session for every user of your system, not just the ones that are expired which is what **clearsessions** does. Sometimes this is fine, but my bet would be that you don't want to wipe valid session data for every single person... say a person who logged in 5 minutes ago.

Comment: @ViaTech Oh, in this case (for packing an old website) this was a perfectly fine outcome.

Answer (score 23):

1. Django 1.6 or Above

   ```
   python manage.py clearsessions
   ```
2. Django 1.5 or lower

   ```
   python manage.py cleanup
   ```
3. From Django Shell

   ```
   from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
   Session.objects.all().delete()
   ```
4. django-session-cleanup
   [cornJob](https://github.com/sandersnewmedia/django-session-cleanup/tree/master/session_cleanup)

Comment: Doesn't the third delete all session rows while `clearsessions` clear only expired sessions?

Comment: This helped me in accessing the sessions table via django model. +1

Answer (score 3):

On my `development server`, I prefer a database command over `python manage.py clearsessions` because you delete all sessions, not just the expired ones (here: MySQL). To login into your database and do:

```
truncate table django_session;
```

BTW, `session` is not a database, but a table (django_session) and an app (`django.contrib.sessions`).

Comment: According to my test it is wrong that clearsessions deletes all sessions. At Django 2.2.7 I can confirm that current sessions stay in the table.

Comment: truncate will remove also active sessions

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I tried this command/attribute and it worked for me.

In the 'base.html' file, I inserted:
{{ request.session.clear_expired }}

This clears expired records from the django_session table when the user clicks on any link in the template after the session expires.

Even so, it is necessary to create a routine to clear expired records over a period longer than one day. This is necessary to clear logs when user closes browser with open sessions.

I used Django 3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Other method:

I'm using Django 3.2 and i recommend using the [django-auto-logout](https://pypi.org/project/django-auto-logout/) package.

It allows active time and idle time session control.

In the template you can use variables together with Javascript.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30792604)

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT execute `Session.objects.all().delete()` nor `TRUNCATE TABLE django_session;`, as that would delete *all* sessions, including active ones!

If you want to clear *expired* sessions programmatically:

```py
from django.core import management

management.call_command('clearsessions')
```