# Clearing sessions in django_session table without logging out current users

Tags: python, django

I am working on sessions in Django.

By default, django stores sessions in `django_session`, I found out there is no way to purge sessions.

Though `clearsessions` can be used to delete rows. It is also recommended to run this as a cron job. But doing this means logging out all logged-in users, right?

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: session database table cleanup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296159/django-session-database-table-cleanup)

Comment: No, `clearsessions` only clears expired sessions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete session key from all users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864711/delete-session-key-from-all-users)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#clearing-the-session-store) states (emphasis from me):

> ## Clearing the session store
>
> As users create new sessions on your website, session data can
>   accumulate in your session store. If you’re using the database
>   backend, the `django_session` database table will grow. If you’re using
>   the file backend, your temporary directory will contain an increasing
>   number of files.
>
> To understand this problem, consider what happens with the database
>   backend. When a user logs in, Django adds a row to the `django_session`
>   database table. Django updates this row each time the session data
>   changes. If the user logs out manually, Django deletes the row. But if
>   the user does not log out, the row never gets deleted. A similar
>   process happens with the file backend.
>
> Django does not provide automatic purging of expired sessions.
>   Therefore, **it’s your job to purge expired sessions** on a regular basis.
>   Django provides a clean-up management command for this purpose:
>   `clearsessions`. It’s recommended to call this command on a regular
>   basis, for example as **a daily cron job**.
>
> Note that the cache backend isn’t vulnerable to this problem, because
>   caches automatically delete stale data. Neither is the cookie backend,
>   because the session data is stored by the users’ browsers.

Found this link in [Abid A's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7296233/1218980).

## The [`clearsessions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#django-contrib-sessions) command

> Can be run as a cron job or directly to clean out expired sessions.

So it won't log off every user.

As mentioned by  Kevin Christopher Henry in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753183/django-clearing-sessions-in-django-session-table/38753254?noredirect=1#comment64882372_38753183) and in the other [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37221549/1218980) of your question [flagged by e4c5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753183/django-clearing-sessions-in-django-session-table/38753254?noredirect=1#comment64884597_38753183).

Comment: this is okay!..but doing this will log out all logged in users..right?

Comment: @sachsure I updated the answer with more info from the doc.

Comment: @EmileBergeron, do you know if the clearsessions command can possibly return any result, so the log of the cron job has actually any trace of the partivular run?

Comment: @AdrianChrostowski not sure since I can't test it right now, but I think django commands will return an error code if they fail.

Comment: Why is that SLOW?. Since it boiles down to simple SQL, why is that slow?

Comment: @jobima What do you mean? Running the command on your project is slow for you right now?

Comment: @EmileBergeron exactly. It takes a few minutes. Isn't it wierd? I want to use it on production site but I am worried it somehow blocks the other SQL petitions from the web.

Comment: @jobima it depends on the size of the database (lots of expired sessions?) and the spec of the server it runs on. That's why it's best to be clear sessions as a nightly cron job.

Answer (score 18):

1. Django 1.6 or Above

   `python manage.py clearsessions`
2. Django 1.5 or lower

   `python manage.py cleanup`
3. From Django Shell

   ```py
   from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
   Session.objects.all().delete()
   ```
4. django-session-cleanup
   [**cronJob**](https://github.com/sandersnewmedia/django-session-cleanup/tree/master/session_cleanup)
5. clearing session in logout( based on session key present in request)

```py
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session  
session_key = request.data['sessionKey']
session = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
Session.objects.filter(session_key=session).delete()
Session.objects.all().delete()
```

Comment: Getting a `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'` in line `session_key = request.data['sessionKey']`

Comment: There's a logout() function for the fifth one above that does a bit more than your version (like sending signals).

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT execute `Session.objects.all().delete()` nor `TRUNCATE TABLE django_session;`, as that would delete *all* sessions, including active ones!

If you want to clear *expired* sessions programmatically:

```py
from django.core import management

management.call_command('clearsessions')
```

Answer (score -3):

The newer versions of Django allow:

```py
request.session.clear()
```

Comment: Could you specify which are "the newer versions"?

Comment: This just clears the data in the current session dictionary, it doesn't answer the question at all. And it was already available a long time ago (since 1.8 at least), so it's not even new.

Comment: -1. Very brief answer, doesn't explain what the command does or how to implement it, and apparently *does not in fact do what the OP asked for* so it's incorrect on top of that. Recommend deletion.